# Converting raw data into customised xml

Tags: java, xml

I want to convert the raw file into the below format using Java -

Raw Input:

```
state | abc
country | FR-FRA
```

Output:

```
<data attr ="StateFr">abc</data>
<data attr ="country">FR-FRA</data>
```

State attribute should be appended with the country code shown above. Can someone help me regarding this.

Comment: StackOverflow is designed for asking questions and getting answers. This is not a question, it's asking for someone to do your work. It's not clear where your difficulties lie, or what part of the problem you are struggling with.

Comment: I should point out that the above is not XML in itself. It'll need a root node...

Answer (score 1):

Java Stream API can help

```
    String raw ="name1|value1\n" +
                    "name2|value2";
    String template = "<data attribute=\"%s\">%s</data>";
    String output = Arrays.stream(raw.split("\n"))
            .map(rawPair -> rawPair.split("\\|"))
            .map(pair -> String.format(template, pair[0], pair[1]))
            .collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
```

will output

```
<data attribute="name1">value1</data>
<data attribute="name2">value2</data>
```

But having specific business logic requires a bit more movements. *Get country code first* and then *decorate* you attribute name on stream processing

```
    BiFunction<String, String, String> decorate = (String name, String code) -> {
        if ("state".equals(name)) {
            return name + code;
        } else {
            return name;
        }
    };
    Function<String, String> countryCode = (String source) -> {
        String head = "country|";
        int start = source.indexOf(head) + head.length();
        return source.substring(start, start + 2);
    };

    String code = countryCode.apply(raw);

    ...
    .map(pair -> String.format(template, decorate.apply(pair[0], code), pair[1]))
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Regarding the country code fetch. I have a raw large file which has the country code coming next to state and Im reading file one by one.

Comment: That definitely worth mentioning in the task statement ) Is it also required to output transformed entries in the same order they appear in the raw source?

Comment: Yes it is required to be in same order

Comment: You've left out what to me is the only difficult part of the problem, namely escaping special characters correctly. This requires a proper XML serialization library.

Comment: "This requires a proper XML serialization library". Yes. I would suggest the above is suitable in restricted cases

Answer (score 0):

With new requirements

1. a raw file is large
2. a raw file has the country code coming next to state
3. reading file one by one.
4. it is also required to output transformed entries in the same order they appear in the raw source.

you should

1. recognize *sate* and keep it, not producing next entry yet
2. recognize subsequent *country*, update *state* kept and release both *state* and *contry* entries

so here I employ sort of shallow buffer for this role

```
    String raw = "name|value1\n" +
            "state|some-state1\n" +
            "country|fr-fra\n" +
            "name|value2\n" +
            "state|some-state2\n" +
            "country|en-us\n";

    class ShallowBuffer {
        private String stateKey = "state";
        private String countryKey = "country";
        private String[] statePairWaitingForCountryCode = null;

        private List<String[]> pump(String[] pair) {
            if (stateKey.equals(pair[0])) {
                statePairWaitingForCountryCode = pair;
                return Collections.emptyList();
            }
            if (countryKey.equals(pair[0])) {
                statePairWaitingForCountryCode[0] = statePairWaitingForCountryCode[0] + pair[1].substring(0, 2);
                String[] stateRelease = statePairWaitingForCountryCode;
                statePairWaitingForCountryCode = null;
                return Arrays.asList(stateRelease, pair);
            }
            return Collections.singletonList(pair);
        }
    }

    ShallowBuffer patience = new ShallowBuffer();
    String template = "<data attribute=\"%s\">%s</data>";
    String output = Arrays.stream(raw.split("\n"))
            .map(rawPair -> rawPair.split("\\|"))
            .map(patience::pump)
            .flatMap(Collection::stream)
            .map(pair -> String.format(template, pair[0], pair[1]))
            .collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
```

this will output

```
 <data attribute="name">value1</data>
 <data attribute="statefr">some-state1</data>
 <data attribute="country">fr-fra</data>
 <data attribute="name">value2</data>
 <data attribute="stateen">some-state2</data>
 <data attribute="country">en-us</data>
```

Shallow buffer is mutable, so you cannot use *parallel* methods in your stream-chain.
It also mean marking it accesible out of the scope will require synchronisation work. 
And you still need to capitalize the first letter of a country code )

Comment: You've left out what to me is the only difficult part of the problem, namely escaping special characters correctly. This requires a proper XML serialization library.

Comment: Thanks this really helped!

Comment: if an answer helps you - _accept_ it, then further readers will notice suitable answer first and, of cause, it's author will get credits for the answer in the system. If you just like the answer - you can _upvote_ it. For the same reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Run the following XSLT 3.0 stylesheet:

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
     version="3.0" expand-text="yes" xmlns:f="f">

<xsl:template name="xsl:initial-template">
 <root>
  <xsl:iterate select="unparsed-text-lines('input.txt')">
    <xsl:param name="prev-parts" select="()"/>
    <xsl:on-completion>
       <attribute name="{$prev-parts[1]}">{$prev-parts[2]}</attribute>
    </xsl:on-completion>  
    <xsl:variable name="parts" select="tokenize(., '\|')"/>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="$parts[1] = 'country'">
        <attribute name="{f:titleCase($prev-parts[1])}{f:titleCase(substring-before($parts[2], '-')}">{$prev-parts[2]}</attribute>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <attribute name="{$prev-parts[1]}>{$prev-parts[2]}</attribute>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
    <xsl:next-iteration>
      <xsl:with-param name="prev-parts" select="$parts"/>
    </xsl:next-iteration>
  </xsl:iterate>
 </root>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:function name="f:titleCase">
  <xsl:param name="in"/>
  <xsl:sequence select="upper-case(substring($in, 1, 1))||substring($in, 2)"/>
</xsl:function>    
</xsl:transform>
```

Note that unlike other solutions presented here, this one will always produce well-formed XML output. (We see an awful lot of problems on StackOverflow from people receiving so-called XML that has been incorrectly generated because it ignores the problem of escaping special characters.)